# Combine cells retaining formatting within a sheet

Tags: google-sheets, text-formatting

I want to combine columns of texts while preserving the formatting (e.g., underline, *italics*). How can I do that?

I know how to use `=C1&CHAR(10)&C2` ...
but the formatting is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. You will need to assign text formatting again after you merge it:

[image: 0]

Comment: Can I at least assign the formatting within the formula?

Comment: nope, not possible either

Comment: @KumāraBhikkhu you are welcome -  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Since it doesn't answer my question, I think I shouldn't vote up or accept your answer. Sorry.

Comment: Heh… by that strict of logic, your question amounts to a Google Sheets feature request, and is off-topic—should we be down-voting or voting to close? Back to being serious, Stack Exchange works best when good questions appear in peoples' search results, and good answers rise to the top; so this answer gets +1 from me in any case since "This is not possible" is the answer, whether we're happy about it or not.